# How to use HTTPS in development?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket, https, certificate

I'm working on a simple chat app. App is created with ReactJS and uses REST api from Spring Boot app. Communication between client and server is based on both HTTP and WebSocket. I need to upgrade protocols to HTTPS and WSS but I can't succeed. I'm using self-signed certificates. I installed them, but I'm getting INVALID_COMMON_NAME when accessing REST API from ReactJS app (https://private_ipv4:443/...). I also tried to set private IP address as CN and SAN for certificate but, still doesn't work. Some know how to fix it?

Accessing REST api directly through browser or postman works fine, but through app doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the certificate does not match the hostname or IP address of the server. You don't see the error through a browser or Postman becuase the browser or client are configured to accept self-signed certificates. To fix this issue, the CN and SAN fields of your SSL cert should match the hostname or IP addres of your server.  Have you installed the self-signed certificate in the trusted root sotre of the client's OS and browser?

Comment: I already set CN and SAN to private ip address of my server and added certificate to Trusted Root Certification Auth.